# Wordpress - Custom post type posts not using single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have just upgraded to 4.7.3 and have an issue with my custom post types.
The posts were displaying fine until the upgrade, and I’m not sure how to fix this.

They all now use the index.php file instead of single.php, which isn’t right. My static / list pages all work fine, just the custom posts.

Please help. My PHP isn’t the greatest. I have tried deactivating plugins and it’s still not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried _Settings -> Permalinks -> Save changes_ ? Try to do that, without changing anything else. Also, use another browser / clear cache

Comment: Please check the file permissions also.

Comment: Thanks, both. @AntonisTsimourtos, your solution worked: I changed the permalink settings for my custom post types, changed them back, then did the same for Wordpress permalink settings. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

To display single page of custom post type you need to create new 'single.php' file with appending your custom post type name in last with the new file.

For example, if your custom post type is 'book' then you need to create new file with name,

```
single-book.php
```

and save your permalink structure again.
Hope this might be work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the single.php of the default WordPress folder and make it useable for your CPT. Check this link of Codex.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates